# How can I supress warning "removing `initialize' may cause serious problems" in rspec?

Tags: rspec, rspec-mocks

I have a test that does:

`allow_any_instance_of(GoogleMapsService::Client).to receive(:initialize)`

and I'm getting `warning: removing 'initialize' may cause serious problems`, but I didn't find any other way to stub this.

How can I solve it in another way so I don't get the warning or how can I silence the warning?

Thank you very much

Comment: Why don't you call `:new` instead of `:initialize` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The #initialize method is called on the instance while the #new method is called on the class so you could do something like:

```
allow(GoogleMapsService::Client).to receive(:new)
```

See [This issue](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/issues/130) for more context.

Answer (score 0):

I mean why don't you do this

```
allow(GoogleMapsService::Client).to receive(:new)
```

instead of

```
allow(GoogleMapsService::Client).to receive(:initialize)
```

Comment: Mmm that doesn't work: `GoogleMapsService::Client does not implement #new`

Comment: @LeticiaEsperon, That is because `.new` is called on the class itself rather than on an instance of the class.  Try using `allow(GoogleMapsService::Client).to receive(:new)`.